# Can the old region be largger than the setting of JVM

Tags: java, jvm, g1gc

I have a project with G1.The JVM Parameters are:

```
    -Xmx12288m 
 -Xms12288m 
 -Xss256k
 -XX:G1NewSizePercent=35
 -XX:G1MaxNewSizePercent=60
 -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=200
 -XX:+UseG1GC
 -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow
 -XX:MinHeapFreeRatio=30
 -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=50 
 -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions
```

There is a youngc with the GC log:
2024-01-25T19:25:58.266+0800: 7483.790: [GC pause (G1 Evacuation Pause) (young) (to-space exhausted), 1.5322861 secs]
   [Eden: **6828.0M**(6828.0M)->**0.0B**(4148.0M) Survivors: 272.0M->152.0M Heap: 11993.5M(12288.0M)->**9724.0M**(12288.0M)]

My heap capacity is 12G(min and max), the G1NewSizePercent is 35%, which means the max capacity of old region is 7987.2M. But the gc log shows the eden was 0 , survivors is 152M, heap is 9724M after younggc.

(1) Is the old region capacity: 9724(total capacity) - 152 (survivors) - 0(eden) = 9572M ?
(2) If (1) is correct, why can the old region capacity be larger than 7987.2M?

Comment: Do you have any humongous objects maybe?

Comment: *"G1NewSizePercent is 35%, which means the max capacity of old region is 7987.2M"* - No, `G1NewSizePercent` does not limit the total capacity of Old regions. Note that the term "region" in G1 terminology refers to a large block of the heap (typically several MB). Heap has many regions, and each of them can change its type at runtime. Besides Old, New and Survivor regions there are also Humongous regions.